# Lambda implicit capture fails with variable declared from structured binding

Tags: c++, lambda, visual-studio-2017, c++17, structured-bindings

With the following code, I get a compile error `C2065 'a': undeclared identifier` (using visual studio 2017):

```
[] {
    auto [a, b] = [] {return std::make_tuple(1, 2); }();
    auto r = [&] {return a; }(); //error C2065
}();
```

However, the following code compiles:

```
[] {
    int a, b;
    std::tie(a, b) = [] {return std::make_tuple(1, 2); }();
    auto r = [&] {return a; }();
}();
```

I thought that the two samples were equivalent. Is it a compiler bug or am I missing something ?

Comment: Might be related: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/68vhir/whats_the_rationale_for_this_reference_to_local/

Comment: gcc 8.1.1 compiles without complaining. clang 6.0.1 gives an error.

Comment: AFAICS, the fact that (as I can also attest) this now works in `g++` 8 in `-std=c++17` mode implies that either (A) some fix has been treated as a defect and backported, of which I can't find any immediate signs, or (B) `g++` might be allowing it as an extension or even inadvertently.

Comment: C++20 allows structured bindings to be captured (copying them separately if by value).

Comment: @DavisHerring, that's interesting, could you give a reference to the change in the standard which allowed this?

Comment: @ThreeStarProgrammer57: [Yes](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1091r3.html); note that the restriction on capturing them by reference introduced there was later removed (after further analysis established that no other changes were needed to support them *properly*).

Answer (score 133, accepted):

[Core issue 2313](https://wg21.link/CWG2313) changed the standard so that structured bindings are never names of variables, making them never capturable.

[P0588R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0588r1.html)'s reformulation of lambda capture wording makes this prohibition explicit:

> If a lambda-expression [...] captures a structured binding (explicitly
>   or implicitly), the program is ill-formed.

Note that this wording is supposedly a placeholder while the committee figures out exactly how such captures should work.

<sub>Previous answer kept for historical reasons:</sub>

---

This technically should compile, but there's a bug in the standard here.

The standard says that lambdas can only capture variables. And it says that a non-tuple-like structured binding declaration doesn't introduce variables. It introduces names, but those names aren't names of variables.

A tuple-like structured binding declaration, on the other hand, *does* introduce variables. `a` and `b` in `auto [a, b] = std::make_tuple(1, 2);` are actual 
reference-typed variables. So they can be captured by a lambda.

Obviously this is not a sane state of affairs, and the committee knows this, so a fix should be forthcoming (though there appears be some disagreement over exactly how capturing a structured binding should work).

Comment: A friendly reminder that this issue is resolved. Currently, the tuple-like structured binding introduces variables of unique names, `a` and `b` names the glvalues referred to by those variables.

Comment: @PasserBy is this fix implemented in a current compiler?

Comment: This is fixed by P0588R1 and implemented in GCC 8; @T.C. would you update the answer?

Comment: @BenjaminBuch It's not at all clear what "fix" you mean. That is the same paper that T.C. already cited as *forbidding* capture of structured bindings into lambdas - which seems very unfortunate to me - at least until the Committee decides on non-placeholder wording to replace this behaviour. Did you mean a different paper? If so, I would appreciate its correct number.

Comment: @underscore_d You are right, I didn't read it carefully and mixed it with something else, sorry!

Comment: @BenjaminBuch I'm pretty sure it *does* need an update, as obviously SBs should be capturable to really be useful, and I think I recall a paper proposing to change the wording on "entities" and such to enable this. On glancing at the final draft, the section on lambda captures seems only to refer to entities, and not to forbid structured bindings (yay), but I'm too tired to be sure I've noticed everything, and I'm definitely not scrolling up to the bit on entities. :)

Comment: There's a paper in the pipeline that would change this, but nothing has happened to the working paper yet, so there's nothing to update.

Comment: me at each and every phrase: WTF 

Comment: Did anything change for C++20? GCC now allows you to capture variables from structured bindings while clang doesn't. Which compiler is correct?

Comment: *A tuple-like structured binding declaration, on the other hand, does introduce variables.* Clang 12 still does not accept it: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9zc8o3scT

Comment: Years passed, Clang 14 still doesn't support this.

Comment: Calng 15 still doesn't work. Clang is weird.

Comment: @facetus Clang 16 reporting for duty

Comment: @sehe Thank you for an update! A couple of more years and maybe Clang will finally implement all C++20 features.

Answer (score 66):

A possible workaround is to use a lambda capture with the initializer. The following code compiles fine in Visual Studio 2017 15.5.

```
[] {
    auto[a, b] = [] {return std::make_tuple(1, 2); }();
    auto r = [a = a] {return a; }();
}();
```

Comment: mind blown . this is like python lambda default argument serving as a neo capture list. note: your stuff also works in clang (which is the only barking compiler of this whole issue) https://godbolt.org/z/PcAZNG

Comment: Although note that this is more like "captures by value".

Comment: I was getting 'Structured binding cannot be captured' error while compiling code using C++ 17 standard. This workaround worked for me. Thanks. And it is OK to capture by value if it is a primitive data type.

Comment: Another (more verbose) option I've occasionally used, that avoids the potential copy, is to capture a pointer. In the above example: `auto r = [a = &a] { return *a; }();`

Answer (score 26):

Now lambda could capture structured binding since c++20, see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Comment: Nice, thanks, if you get a chance it would be great to link the relevant section in the standard.

Comment: I guess it is since C++17 ?

Comment: @Silviu, the this link states "Structured bindings cannot be captured by lambda expressions. (until C++20)"

Comment: Clang 14 still doesn't support it, even if compiled with `-std=c++20`. GCC is the best, Clang...

Comment: Clang 15 still doesn't work.

Comment: Works in clang trunk: https://godbolt.org/z/j4E4oYn83

Answer (score 9):

You can use init-capture like this, as suggested in https://burnicki.pl/en/2021/04/19/capture-structured-bindings.html. The variable is captured by reference, so there is no overhead, and no need to deal with pointers.

```
auto [a, b] = [] { return std::make_tuple(1, 2); }();
auto r = [&a = a] { return a; }();
```

Using the same name both for structured binding and for its reference can be misleading, but actually it means

```
auto r = [&a_ref = a] { return a_ref; }();
```

As far as I know, it works on all compilers starting from C++17 and above, including clang.