# Why does GCC diagnose a unused variable for structured bindings while Clang doesn't?

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, c++17, structured-bindings

Let's start with a minimal example:

```
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    auto [a, b] = std::pair(1, 'A');
    return a;
}
```

Compiling with GCC 7.3 passing `-std=c++17` and `-Wunused-variable`, and running it:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:5:15: warning: unused variable 'b' [-Wunused-variable]
     auto [a, b] = std::pair(1, 'A');
               ^
```

GCC may be correctly reporting the absent use of `b`, but it wrongly calls it a variable. Quoting [[dcl.struct.bind]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#1):

> A structured binding declaration introduces the *identifiers* v0, v1, v2, … of the *identifier-list* as names ([basic.scope.declarative]) of structured bindings.

So `b` clearly isn't a variable, but rather a *name*. Compiling the same code with Clang 6.0.0, and with the same flags, we get no warning whatsoever. Removing the `return a;` statement from the code:

```
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    auto [a, b] = std::pair(1, 'A');
    // return a;
}
```

and compiling it again with Clang, we get:

```
<source>:5:10: warning: unused variable '[a, b]' [-Wunused-variable]
    auto [a, b] = std::pair(1, 'A');
         ^
```

Which, from my interpretation, correctly treats `[a, b]` as a variable, and `a` and `b` separately as just names. **My question** then is **why does GCC diagnose a warning for `b` being unused, considering that the variable is in fact being used in the `return a;` statement from the first code?**

Comment: What return statement? Only `a` is returned, not `b`. P.S. because this is a common idiom, with structured bindings, it's been reported that this warning message is no longer issued by gcc 8.

Comment: If they are not variables, how come you can take their addresses? For example `auto p = &a;`

Comment: In this particular case, `b` is a variable. But in general `b` might be anything, including a lambda or a pointer to a function.

Comment: @NeilButterworth they are names for the underlying members of the struct. The actual variable doesn't get an identifier.

Comment: That they are names doesn't conflict with that they are variables. Or simply put, what else can they be?

Comment: @PasserBy the standard clearly says that they are names of lvalues, which is a different term from variable: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind

Comment: I'm surprised. Structured bindings are indeed considered something different. They are their own category. However I doubt the error message is meant to be taken that literally and precisely, to mean exactly a variable as defined in the standard.

Comment: @PasserBy you'd be more surprised to know that [it was indeed meant to address a different term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114214/lambda-implicit-capture-fails-with-variable-declared-from-structured-binding).

Comment: "Why does GCC diagnose a unused variable for structured bindings while Clang doesn't?" - Because compilers are different and diagnose different things (and have different bugs) and also have different levels of standard conformance.

Comment: @Mário Feroldi I don't believe I said the question was invalid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was indeed a bug in `gcc`: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=81767 and was solved in: https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=248483