# structure binding followed by a lambda capture creates a clang compilation error

Tags: c++, clang, c++17

When using c++17 structure bindings and used these variables to be captured by a lambda function, clang fails to compile but it does work for MSVC  and GCC. Here is the code ([on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sEKf57)):

```
std::tuple<int, double, long> f() { return { 1, 2., 3 }; }
auto [a,b,c] = f();
[a, &b, other = c]() {
    std::cout << a << b << other << std::endl;
}();
```

Clang returns an error for `a` and `b`: `error: 'a' in capture list does not name a variable`.
I am not sure this is a valid code though. Can someone tell which compiler does things right?

Thank you

Comment: [This is a duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114214/lambda-implicit-capture-fails-with-variable-declared-from-structured-binding) Long story short: a technicality in the standard means that `a`, `b`, and `c` are just "aliases" for the components of the unnamed `std::tuple` variable bound by the structured binding, not variables/references themselves. Therefore, they can't be captured. This is an issue with the standard, so Clang is correct here.