# error: reference to local binding 'x' declared in enclosing function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, language-lawyer

A similar code has failed to compile in our pipeline (Clang 15.0.2), but I have managed to reproduce the error.
https://godbolt.org/z/o4cfveWY8

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    const auto [x, y] = [&]{
        const int x = 42;
        const int y = 815;
        return std::tuple{x, y};
    }();

    [&x]{
        int y = x;
        std::cout << y << '\n';
    }();

    return 0;
}
```

The error Clang outputs is:

```
<source>:11:7: error: 'x' in capture list does not name a variable
    [&x]{
      ^
<source>:12:17: error: reference to local binding 'x' declared in enclosing function 'main'
        int y = x;
                ^
<source>:5:17: note: 'x' declared here
    const auto [x, y] = [&]{
```

Both GCC and MSVC compile this code fine.
Who is in the wrong here?

Comment: Dup of [Lambda implicit capture fails with variable declared from structured binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114214/lambda-implicit-capture-fails-with-variable-declared-from-structured-binding)

Comment: Clang 16.0.0 reports that the capture would need C++20.