# Why does NRVO not work on a structured binding?

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

#### The Y part.

Consider these [examples](https://godbolt.org/z/3jj44zcxG):

```
#include <iostream>

struct movable
{
    movable() {
        std::cout << "movable()\n";
    }

    movable(movable&&) noexcept {
        std::cout << "movable(&&)\n";
    }

    movable(const movable&) noexcept {
        std::cout << "movable(const &)\n";
    }

    ~movable() {
        std::cout << "~movable()\n";
    }
};

movable rvo()
{
    return {};
}

movable nrvo()
{
    movable m;
    return m;
}

movable cnrvo()
{
    const movable m;
    return m;
}

movable binding_nrvo()
{
    struct binding { movable m; };
    auto [m] = binding{};
    // explicit move is required
    // return std::move(m);

    // otherwise a copy would be made
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::cout << "rvo:\n";
        movable m = rvo();
    }

    {
        std::cout << "\nnrvo:\n";
        movable m = nrvo();
    }

    {
        std::cout << "\ncnrvo:\n";
        movable m = cnrvo();
    }

    {
        std::cout << "\nbinding_nrvo:\n";
        movable m = binding_nrvo();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output with `-std=c++17 -O3` is the followng:

```
rvo:
movable()
~movable()

nrvo:
movable()
~movable()

cnrvo:
movable()
~movable()

binding_nrvo:
movable()
movable(const &)
~movable()
~movable()
```

I know that NRVO would not work for a "wrapped" value, for example you have to explicitly use `std::move` like `return std::move(std::get<0>(tuple));` in order to prevent the copy.

But here the binding happens "by value": `auto [m] = binding;`. Hence, I beleive that `m` is a standalone object. **Why doesn't NRVO happen here?**

#### The X part

The question is not about "X", but for the context:
I was experimenting with structured bindings to adopt them for a "go-like" control flow to return errors. The ideal way would be to have something like:

```
const auto [value, err] = getSome();
if (err)
  return err;
```

Without an expected-like return type this appears to me to be the cleanest control flow without resorting to exceptions. I expected this to perform NRVO on the const `err` (like in my example with `cnrvo()`), but it doesn't happen.
And sinse you have to use `std::move`, there's no way to have `value` as const either.
At the end it becomes something like

```
auto [value, errGetSome] = getSome(); // can't have several `err` in the scope
if (!errGetSome)
  return std::move(errGetSome);

// just promise not to modify `value`
const auto& actualValue = value;
```

... which defeats the whole point.
Anyways, I would like an answer to the **whY** part.

Comment: NRVO is not guaranteed. I reckon it just has yet to be implemented in this particular context by GCC (and Clang).

Comment: Because you are returning a const to something that is non-const, so a copy must be made. So it is not even related to structured biding.

Comment: @PepijnKramer can you elaborate? If you are referring to the X part, what do you mean by "something that is non-const"? Do you mean that the "NRVO" actually happens, and the copy happens not as the result of returning `auto [m]`?

Comment: Me bad I misread a bit of code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A structured binding doesn't create N separate objects. It creates a single unnamed variable, plus N (somewhat magical) references to its members.

When the caller allocates the receiving object for NRVO, it can't be expected to allocate excessive space to fit the entire unnamed variable from the sturctured binding, and it might be impossible in the general case.

There's no particular reason why it wouldn't be possible for a simple single-element structured binding like yours, I guess nobody bothered to optimize this special case.

---

Regarding the X part, I don't see a good solution. Don't use structured bindings if you're going to return the whole pair, then you can NRVO the pair itself.

Comment: the "simple single-element" is just a code example. There might be as many as `auto [first, second, third] = getSome(); return third;`. I tend to think that having `return std::move(third);` would be very confusing for a regular developer who has been taught to _"basically never use `std::move` on `return`"_...

Comment: _"Don't use structured bindings if you're going to return the whole pair"_ misses the point. In X `getSome()` already returns a pair/tuple-like type, which can be an internal `struct` with 2 fields. There's not problem in "returning the pair". There's the problem in returning just one of the fields while maintaining  constness.

Comment: The point is that `auto [a, b] = func(); return a;` is equivalent to `auto unamedObj = func(); return unnamedObj.firstField;`.  `a` is not a separate object; rather it's a magical non-reference reference that is an alias for a sub-object of the hidden object created by the structured binding.

Comment: @MilesBudnek it looks like the "implementation details". Does the standard guarantee that such an object is necessary to be created? It reminds me of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46114214/9363996

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik *"the "simple single-element" is just a code example. There might be as many as"* Yes. As I said, while a single-element binding is theoretically possible to support, multi-element is impossible. *"There's not problem in "returning the pair". There's the problem in returning just one"* Again, as I said, I don't see a good solution in the general case. *"Does the standard guarantee that such an object is necessary to be created?"* Yes, see http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#1